# Spring MVC Identifying the Controller used for a given url/view

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-mvc, controller, view

I am working on a well undocumented project and I was wondering if is it possible to get the controller used for a certain url or view?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more information, one of the easiest ways is to turn on DEBUG logging for the Spring servlet. For example if you are using log4j:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.web.servlet=DEBUG
```

After you turn that on, you'll see log entries anytime a page is hit like this:

```
Mapping [/some/path] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [com.myapp.controller.MyController@4cda661a]
```

Anyway, there are various ways to do this, including scanning the code for the view name or path. Another approach would be to create a interceptor that logs some additional information for every request.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Spring Tool Suite](http://spring.io/tools/sts) (comes either standalone or as an add-on for Eclipse). It's essentially Eclipse with extra Spring-specific features, one of them is what you're looking for:

[image: Show RequestMappings]